# Reference request on numerical semigroups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, semigroups

I watched some talks about numeric semigroups, and their relation with algebraic geometry (such as Weierstrass Semigroup of a curve), and I'm interested in take a deeper look in this topic, can anyone appoint some references in order to start the study in this area? My background is the first 3 chapters of Hatshorne, and some familiarity with monads and vector bundles.

Thank you so much for your time!